# Change the handle of the displayed node programmatically

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have this tree displaying the file structure, I have folders and files. Some folders are not accessible and I am disabling them (they appear as grayed out in the UI) - I am doing this in the node renderer. The thing is that these folders still have the "+" icon (handle or what's it called) before the folder icon. I am trying to change that.

Is there a way for me to change the node handle from "+" to "-"  programatically ? Like when I decide that a node is not accessible to make the handle "-" in the node renderer or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the "minus" icon/handle is rendered when a node is expanded (e.g. you can see the content of the node). I am assuming that you want the node to *not* have any children, therefore no minus or plus handle will be rendered.

---

If you want these nodes to not have any children you can call [setAllowsChildren(false)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#setAllowsChildren%28boolean%29) on them. Or if you are implementing the [`TreeNode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) interface you return `true` from [`isLeaf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html#isLeaf%28%29).

Comment: Cool, this works. I have modified the behavior of isLeaf() and now the + icon don't appear anymore. Thanks